# Python, Pyglet, win32 API, COM: how to call IStream::Release if all I have is a pointer?

Tags: python, winapi, gdi, pyglet, pythoncom

I am trying to fix a memory leak in Pyglet. It occurs only on win32, as it involves IStream object, allocated by ole32.CreateStreamOnHGlobal not being freed.

You can find the issue #552 on Pyglet tracker [by clicking here.](http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/issues/detail?id=552)

As you can see in the source code, the release of the stream was left out as a TODO item:

- [line 148](http://code.google.com/r/michaldtz-fix-552/source/browse/pyglet/image/codecs/gdiplus.py#148)
- [line 204](http://code.google.com/r/michaldtz-fix-552/source/browse/pyglet/image/codecs/gdiplus.py#204)

Comment in line 204 even includes my question: *How to call IUnknown::Release on stream?*

The stream is allocated in [line 142](http://code.google.com/r/michaldtz-fix-552/source/browse/pyglet/image/codecs/gdiplus.py#142). As pyglet does not relies on external dependencies, I don't think I can use pywin32. All we know at the python side about the stream object is [gdiplus.py line 53](http://code.google.com/r/michaldtz-fix-552/source/browse/pyglet/image/codecs/gdiplus.py#53)

```
LPSTREAM = c_void_p
```

So, this is my background - the situation and the limitations. Now, my question - again. How can I call IStream::Release if all I have is a pointer? I have a long-running process that loads different images every 5 seconds or so and it looks like it is an issue for me. I can understand C/C++ and I even do some programming from time to time, but I am not win32 api expert by *any* means. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyglet includes a COM module that interfaces with IUnknown (pyglet.com, used by the dsound audio driver).

This module didn't exist when the GDI+ interface was written.

You could rewrite the image loading to use COM objects instead of the C interface, or just use the steam pointer you have as the this pointer of an IUnknown.

Comment: I will sure look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this helps, it pertains to same problem.

http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/23946-closing-excel-application

Comment: Well, I thought about writing some C code to perform this task already, but as one of pyglet's ideas is not relying on 3rd-party libraries. Maybe it is possible to do some other way, using pure python?